# Joomla front-end login leads to 404 error

Tags: joomla

I recently updated my website from Joomla 3.6.2 to 3.7.2.
Everything is OK except the front-end logging, which now leads to 404.

### Diagnosis

- One can still create a new user from here, but not logging.
- When a logging attempt is made, the url changes to /index.php but I get a 404 error page.
- If I try to directly access /index.php (ie. without logging), I get the correct main page.
  Hence I would be tempted to say htaccess is not faulty here.
- The /administrator logging page works perfectly.

Therefore, I suspect the problem is in the front-end logging module.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You have activated URL friendly? With update you have keep .htaccess file

Comment: @Rinos I tried with and without URL friendly, with and without URL rewriting.
Nothing seems to be changing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that disabling the "Encrypt login form" option has it working again.

HTTPS being disabled on this site, I guess it's logical.